# Intellij: What is the shortcut for going to the next/previous error in the current file?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, if you press CTRL+1, the cursor is set on the first error and there the IDE presents you some solutions. In IDEA, you press ALT+ENTER for some solutions, but I don't know how to make the cursor to go to the error.

Comment: why not accept the (obvious) correct answer?

Answer (score 53):

<kbd>F2</kbd> can be used to navigate through all errors/warnings in current file in circle.

After compilation: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Up/Down</kbd> can be used to navigate through any results: search results/compilation results.

Comment: For those whose screen flipped upside down when they did this: https://superuser.com/questions/373832/disable-alt-arrow-display-flip-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: What are the names of those commands? (I already have my Keymap all messed up.)

Comment: "Next Highlighted Error" / "Previous Highlighted Error" for F2, "Next Occurrence" / "Previous Occurrence" for "Ctrl+Alt+Arrows"

Comment: Thanks a lot @bealex for mentioning the name of the commands. These should be in the answer since they are more relevant as they are independent from your current keymap. And people might also want to change the default shortcut

Answer (score 13):

Besides, you can choose going to next error only (ignore warning) by:

1. Right click the [Validation Side Bar](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/familiarize-yourself-with-intellij-idea-editor.html).
2. On the context menu, choose the `Go to high priority problems only`

it works for Intellij Idea 12

Comment: Excellent tip: Right click the Validation Side Bar.

Answer (score 8):

For intellij 2016:

1. Go to Settings \ Editor \ General;
2. Scroll down unil "Error highlighting";
3. Check "'next Error' action goes to high priority only";
4. Now <kbd>F2</kbd> only navigate on errors when current file contains errors. If no errors, <kbd>F2</kbd> navigate on warnings;

Comment: pro tip: `'next Error' action goes to high priority only` is like second from the bottom :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have a large code-base with a lot of "optimization potential", and the fact that "Next error" was often navigating me something that was not a compiler error was indeed a pain.

Comment: By now, this has been moved to `Editor > Code Editing`