# Go to next compiler error across project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I spend a lot of time going back and forth between SBT and IntelliJ, getting a file, line number, and error from SBT and navigating to it in IntelliJ. Is there a way to automate this at all? Even if it's only via IntelliJ's compiler, I'd love to be able to navigate to the next error project-wide.

Comment: @ManuelRomeiro No, not a duplicate. The Question [you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2678855/642706) seems focused on moving to next compiler error within the file currently being edited. This Questions seems to ask for how to find next compiler error across the project, across *multiple* files. These Questions could indeed have different answers, different features for each situation.

Comment: On that case, the shortcut is ctrl + alt + up / down like an bellow answer. Warning, this shortcut is in collision with some graphic card shortcuts on windows, that invert the the screen, and with multiple screen layout on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2022 UPDATE

This is a whole project, error to error, one-click solution after a 2-second setup. For both setups, optionally disable `generate warnings` for your compiler.

**Windows/Linux Setup**

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> or click `Project Errors` tab of `Problems tool window`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad+</kbd> or click [image: expand all]
   to expand all errors

**MacOS Setup**

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> or click `Project Errors` tab of `Problems tool window`
2. <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or click [image: expand all] to expand all errors

Now `click` the first error in the `Project Errors` tab,  fix it, then `click` the next error. Works regardless of build tool and may work in older versions of intellij than 2022.1.

Edit: Credit @Manuel Romeiro - the answer in his comment worked for a while, but stopped when intellij got confused somehow. Will update my answer if I figure that out.

Thanks @meridsa for providing setup step 1 for Mac. Also to @K. Symbol for syntax for showing keys in an answer (very cool).

Answer (score 85):

To navigate between errors or warnings in IntelliJ you can do one of the following:

- Use keyboard shortcuts <kbd>F2</kbd> (Next) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (Previous) respectively.
- On the main menu, choose `Navigate` | `Next / Previous Highlighted Error`.

Comment: This seems to only navigate through errors/warnings in a single file.  Quite often I want to navigate through all the errors/warnings in the project, I haven't found a nice way to do that yet.

Comment: @KenWilliams one of the options in your case would be to switch from default view (Project) to "Problems".

Comment: Clarifying @pavjel, because this took me a long time to find: "Problems" is not a separate tool window like "Project", it's a "tab" in the Project tool (which, confusingly also contains a *tab* called Project).  These tabs are accessed (depending if you have "Group Tabs" selected under the "gear" icon) via a subtle dropdown at the top of the view that by default says "Project".  This could be much more discoverable!

Comment: Also, I have not found a way in the Problems tab of the Project tool to jump with one or two keystrokes to the next/previous error in the project as requested in the original question.

Comment: It seems that on mac, F2 is not working. What do I do then?

Comment: yeah, this is one of the bigger problems in intellij in terms of workflow that could easily be fixed but hasn't been. intellij is mostly quite good, but this particular thing is really lacking. The one way you can accomplish this is to bind a key to build and keep hitting it. Intellij will rebuild and then take you to the next error. A little slow, but works.

Comment: This works only inside a single file.

Answer (score 35):

I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to scroll through the list of errors. This is inside the `Compile Messages` window. The `SBT Console` uses the same shortcut, as stated in the [SBT wiki](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/wiki#notification-of-build-failure).

Comment: Thanks for this. Very useful. It's `Cmd` + `Alt` + `Up` / `Down` with Mac OS X 10.5+ keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: This shortcut overlaps with workspace shortcut in Linux distributions like Mint.

Comment: That works the _sbt shell_ tab, which is visible if "Use sbt shell for build" is enabled in build tool preferences. "SBT Console" comes from the (now superseded?) 3rd party "SBT" plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with the Angular compiler output.

Comment: Also doesn't work in a maven project.

Comment: Works great for me in Java + Maven projects under Windows. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

For this specific question, just use <kbd>F2</kbd> (Next) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (Previous);

But for any other questions related to shortcuts of IDEA, searching in the Settings-Keymap is better than in Google.

[image: Settings-Keymap]

Comment: Downvote - duplicate of @AlejandroDG's answer.

Answer (score 7):

To go to next compilation error in the next file:

- `Command-0` (go to messages tab where compile errors are)
- `Down` arrow until get to next error
- `Enter`
- `Esc` to get to back to code where this error is

Comment: This answer is the closest to what the OP is asking (i.e., project-wide navigation); +1. Unfortunately it requires 4 keystrokes. Like all good golf games, it would be cool to figure out how lower that number.

Comment: The `problems tool window` which currently (v. 2021.1) has default keyboard shortcut `cmd + 6`

Comment: On Windows, it's `Alt+6`.

Answer (score 5):

The highly voted answer has not really answered the question. The provided solution of `F2` only navigates through the errors in the current file. But picking up from the comments, the suggestion below is not the ultimate answer but is a little bit closer.

1. Select `Problems` as shown in the image below

[image]

This will list all files that have errors.

2. Use `F2` to navigate through the errors.

At least with this method, it has narrowed down the files with the errors and are just a click away.

Comment: +1 for getting a closer answer to the question. Unfortunately, that menu item doesn't appear if it's a maven project.

Answer (score 2):

For the mac I couldn't find anything that worked until I discovered the following

cmd + 1 -> f2 (on files) -> escape -> f2 (inside file) -> cmd + 1 -> repeat

Comment: Windows analogue for the Mac's _Cmd+1_ combination is _Alt+1_

Answer (score 1):

For going to the next error across the entire project, use Alt+F2 instead of just F2.

Comment: Which IDE is this? Isn't working on 2021 CLion

Comment: Doesn't work in intellij 2022.1

Answer (score -3):

On Mac, you can enable Fn regular key functionality in System Preference.

```
Choose Apple Menu > System Preferences.
Click Keyboard & Mouse.
Click the Keyboard tab.
Select the option Use All F1, F2, Etc. Keys As Standard Function Keys.
Quit System Preferences.
```