# How to navigate to error lines in Android Studio by shortcut?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I navigate to the error lines in a java file?

Isn't there any better way than scrolling to them?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question actully you save my time +1

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I searched for it and found the answer.

1- you can use **F2** and **SHIFT+F2** shortcut to navigate between errors in your document. if there is no error you will be navigated to the warnings.

2- another way that most of us know is to click on the red areas on the scrollbar.

[here is the the link to the **intelliJ IDEA** help documents](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html) which is the base of **Android Studio**.

you can even press **F2** in project window of Android Studio and it will select the files containing errors.

Also if there are no more errors it will point to warnings.

Comment: What a great tool of F2 key, I've been solely concentrated on where any red lines are shown on project lol

Comment: yes it will point the error file if you use it in project window in android studio :/ awesome.

Comment: Menu ➔ Navigate ➔ **Next Highlighted Error** (or assign a keyboard shortcut to this)

Comment: This is nice, but F2 does not jump to the next error, but to the next warning/error/issue. What if I insist on jumping to the next _error_, as the OP asked?

Comment: @IngoSchalk-Schupp as long as there are errors it will jump to errors. once there is no error it jumps to the warnings.

Comment: Hm, that is not the case for me, I just double-checked. It will even jump to typos, even if there are compilation-breaking errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: im on windows. i just made two compile errors and a warning in between now when i press f2 it doesnt go on warning it goes on 1st and 2nd error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501828/1199911 explains how to configure the behaviour of F2 to jump primarily to errors.

Comment: it does jump to errors first on Android Studio. the post you are reffering to is intellij. here we are talking about Android Studio

Comment: F2 goes to the next word that's not in the dictionary

Comment: It also works on Mac. I have an external "PC" keyboard and F2 does the trick.

Comment: but how do you go to next error in the entire project (not just the currrent class)?

Answer (score 7):

**F2** is shortcut key to jump on next error line in java file.
**SHIFT+F2** shortcut to navigate between errors in your document. if there is no error you will be navigated to the warnings.

Comment: I can't get it to jump to the next error in the error list. It only goes to the next silly editor warning in the _current_ file...

Comment: if there are no errors, it jumps to warnings. but it works only in the open document.

Comment: I have updated my answer based upon questions raised in comments

Answer (score 4):

I have another approach, Make Project by press(Ctrl-F9), you can find the errors in Gradle Console(if error exists), just click the red messages will bring you to the error of line directly.

Comment: I want to keep my hands on the keyboard

Comment: It seems that Control+Alt+Down navigates to the next test case that fails. It stops on the case's function name, but that's good enough

Comment: This is not what was asked for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below shortcuts for compilation errors:

- Moving to next / previous highlighted error: `F2`/`Shift + F2`
- Show descriptions of error at caret: `Ctrl + F1`

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

A work-around in windows I use is ALT+N+N (Menu ➔ N̲avigate ➔ N̲ext Highlighted Error).

You can also assign a shortcut for **Next Highlighted Error** in Keymap.

Comment: this is the same as F2